# Targets in Makefile that can not be invoked in shell

Tags: bash, makefile

I got multiple different targets in Makefile but I do not want users to be able to invoke some of them from shell, they are just prerequisites for other targets. For example:

```
target1: pre1 pre2
    ...

target2: target3
    ...

target3:
    ...
```

I would like to disable calling `target3` in bash, in a way that would even prevent bash from displaying `make target3` when `make target` is typed and then `tab` key is pressed.

In short words I do not want people who invoke make with my Makefile to know that `target3` exists. Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Just document the valid `make` targets.

Comment: I could do that but it will not protect me against idiots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to achieve this is to parse the target given to the `make` command by using the variable `MAKECMDGOALS`.

Here is how look like the `Makefile`:

```
ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),)
ALLOWED=1
endif

target1: target2 target3
ifdef ALLOWED 
    echo "target1"
endif

target2:
ifdef ALLOWED 
    echo "target2"
endif

target3: 
ifdef ALLOWED 
    echo "target3"
endif
```

If the `make` has no target, it will execute the `echo`. The `make target3` will not output anything.

If you want to allow a specific target you can add the following:

```
ifeq ($(filter target1,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),target1)
ALLOWED=1
endif
```

Comment: Ok I get the idea, your answer helped me solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

No expert in `make`, bit of looking around the [`GNU make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#How-Make-Works) pages

> By default, make starts with the first target (not targets whose names start with ‘.’).

So the target names that start with a period are not considered when make identifies the default goal. You could try adding the `dot`(`.`) before your target as

```
target1: pre1 pre2
    ...

target2: .target3
    ...

.target3:
    ...
```

to avoid `target3` from shown default when you `tab` is pressed.

Comment: The `dot(.)` did the job!. Thanks, I was looking for some Special Built-in Target Names but `dot(.)` is enough.

Comment: It solved but just partially. Targets with `dor(.)` do not appear when I type `make target` and press `tab` key but I can still invoke this targets from bash by typing `make .target`

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** This answer would completely depend on the linux distro you are using. This is tested on Ubuntu 16.04:

Mark that as a hidden target. Rename it to something that starts with a non-alphanumeric string.

Common option would be `.target3`

From `declare -f _make_target_extract_script`:

```
  /^[^a-zA-Z0-9]/             d             # convention for hidden tgt
```

This line above is a part of the `sed` script that prints the target list for `make`, via the bash-completion function `_make`.